# super() not working in subclass' constructor

Tags: java, super

Superclass:

```
public class CwDB{
protected LinkedList<Entry> dict = null;

public CwDB(String filename){
        this.dict = new LinkedList<Entry>();
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String w = null;
            while((w = br.readLine()) != null ){
                String c = br.readLine();
                this.add(w,c); //adds new Entry to dict
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
public void add(String word, String clue){
    this.dict.add(new Entry(word,clue));
}
...
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class InteliCwDB extends CwDB {

public InteliCwDB(String filename){
    super(filename);
}
}
```

Case 1:

```
CwDB db = new CwDB("src/cwdb.txt");
```

Case 2:

```
InteliCwDB idb = new InteliCwDB("src/cwdb.txt");
```

The problem is that case 1 works perfectly, but case 2 doesn't at all. 
Can you tell me what's wrong?
(I don't get any error/exception, just the idb's list is empty, when db's list has ober +1k elements...)

Comment: How do you test that idb's list is empty? What happens if you put a print statement in the superclass constructor, is it printed?

Comment: It shouldn't matter for the code as shown, but methods called from constructors (such as `add()`) should be marked as `final` to ensure that subclasses don't over-ride them and inadvertently prevent proper initialisation of the superclass.

Comment: Can you print the error trace please

Comment: He's not getting an error trace.

Comment: The code posted so far looks OK - can you show us _exactly_ how you are creating the two objects (i.e. give us a runnable example with `main()` method)?

Comment: @gd1 I check it by printing dict.size() - it's 0. And yes, when i put a print statement in superclass, i get it printed by creating idb.

Comment: If you put a print statement in the parent class' add, does that print upon construction as well?

Comment: @DNA main():
`public static void main(String[] args){
  CwDB db = new CwDB("src/cwdb.txt");
  db.printDB();  
  
  InteliCwDB idb = new InteliCwDB("src/cwdb.txt");
  idb.printDB();   
 }`
printDB() is a test methos, which shows me all elements and dict size.

Comment: try to make use of a debugger (use any modern IDE), and trace step through and watch the changes of variables.

Comment: Ok guys, thank you for your help! Problem solved (Problem was caused by redefined add() method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that:

1. There are no exceptions / stack traces.
2. The `dict` list in the created `InteliCwDB` instance is empty.

If the superclass constructor somehow didn't run, you would have an instance with a `dict` that was `null`.

If some other exception was thrown and not caught, then you wouldn't have a `InteliCwDB` to examine.

So on the face of it, this can only mean that the constructor *is running*, but the file it reads is empty.  In other words you have two different "src/cwdb.txt" files ... in different directories.

---

Other explanations involve questioning your evidence; e.g.

- You are describing the symptoms inaccurately.
- The code you are actually running is substantially different to what you are showing us; e.g. there is some other code that is leaping in and emptying the `dict` after the constructor has created and filled it.  (You haven't declared `dict` to be private ...).
  [ **UPDATE** - this was the explanation: see the OP's comments.  He had overridden `add` in the subclass, and that's where the bug was. ]
- The code you are running doesn't match your source code; i.e. you are not rebuilding / redeploying properly.

---

My advice would be to recheck your processes and your evidence.  And if that doesn't help, then run the application using a debugger, set a breakpoint on the constructor, and single step it so that you can work out what is *really* happening.

Comment: I've created the example based on description in question and it's working pretty well for me: https://compilr.com/evgeniynaydenov/super/Program.java - just run and see that it's working. Therefore the code example in question seems is incomplete or some details are missed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `catch (Exception e)` to your try-catch for the purposes of debugging. An exception that isn't an `IOException` might be causing you problems. So, try like this:

```
public CwDB(String filename){
    this.dict = new LinkedList<Entry>();
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String w = null;
        while((w = br.readLine()) != null ){
            String c = br.readLine();
            this.add(w,c); //adds new Entry to dict
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the way he's running the code (which wasn't shown when you posted your answer, of course!), the exception would show up at the top level anyway...